# How do I access variables with hyphenated names in Smarty?

Tags: php, simplexml, smarty, variable-names

I've got a PHP page that parses an XML file with SimpleXml, then passes that object to a Smarty template. My problem is that the XML file has hyphens in its tag names, e.g. `video-player`. In PHP, this is no problem, I just use `$xml->{'video-player'}` and everything's fine. Smarty, on the other hand, throws a fit when I try to use that syntax.

The only solution I've come up with so far is to use a variable to store the name, e.g.,

```
{ assign var=name value="video-player" }
{ $xml->$name }
```

But this isn't terribly graceful to say the least. Is there another, better, approach to referring to a hyphenated variable name in Smarty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{php}
    echo $xml->{'video-player'};
{/php}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I wonder if there's a way to do it without resorting to falling back to PHP...

Comment: The other way is to change the Smarty delimiters { and } with something different, but it will be easier just to do the {php} thing - http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.escaping.php

Answer (score 0):

In `Dwoo` I'll try with

```
{$xml->`video-player`}
```

maybe in `Smarty` it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put it inside single quotes.

It also works on comparission blocks like:

```
{if $variable == 'hyphenated-value'} it works! {/if}
```

instead of

```
{if $variable == hyphenated-value} do not work! {/if}
```